# Running rake from batch file

Tags: windows, rake, batch-file

When I run rake from within a batch file (.bat) it will exit immediately after the rake script has completed and will not execute any commands after it.

e.g. for the following, it will execute rake but not change directories

```
rake 
cd ..
```

Anyone know how to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you want:

```
call rake
```